# How do I create a module in DotNetNuke 6?

Tags: dotnetnuke

How do I create a module for DotNetNuke v6 in Visual Studio 2010 which connects to a database, without using a `DataSource` control ?

I am a beginner in DotNetNuke and I want to fully understand how to create modules. I have referred Google and I found two links which I think are good, but I need a simple example that includes better comments and connects to the database without using a `DataSource` control.

[Creating a DotNetNuke® Module - For Absolute Beginners!](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12853/Creating-a-DotNetNuke-Module-For-Absolute-Beginner)
[Creating a Super-Fast and Super-Easy DotNetNuke® Module - for Absolute Beginners!](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14613/Creating-a-Super-Fast-and-Super-Easy-DotNetNuke-Mo)

Answer (score 0):

I welcome you to dotnetnuke, indeed it is a great CMS respectively the greatest CMS made with ASP.NET

I would suggest you [basic module development video](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Video-Library/Viewer/Video/15/View/Details/Basic-DotNetNuke-Module-Development.aspx)

And you can go through dotnetnuke official video training library clicking [here](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Video-Library.aspx)

Please also have a look at dotnetnuke blog posts, I would suggest to go through Steve Fabians [blog](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Blogs/BlogID/16.aspx)  you might have a look at Peter Donker and Chris Hammond blogs too.

Last but not least you can have a look at unlimited resources for dotnetnuke at 
[dnncreative.com](http://dnncreative.com)